# jquery not serving partial correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

This should be an easy question for anyone who has served a rails partial via jquery.
This line of code:

```
$('div#status-chg-form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => statusform)) %>').dialog('open');
```

is part of a script to serve a partial in a modal dialog. When the dialog pops up I get only a literal string inside that reads:

```
<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => statusform, :remote => true)) %>
```

This is rails 3.1.

(edited to add:)

```
   $(rails_partial = "<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => statusform)) %>");
   $('div#status-chg-form').append(rails_partial).dialog('open');
```

I have also tried the above to pass the html as a string, thinking there was some problem with the way jquery was processing this. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Is this code inside a .erb file?

Comment: Yes, the partial is an .erb file

Comment: I tried removing the .erb extension from the partial and I still get the same result.

Comment: Is the file which contains `<%=` (not the partial file referred by `status form` is a .erb file? what's the full filename of both of the partial and the file refer to the partial?

Comment: `statusform` isn't in quotes. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Is your erb code being processed as part of an ajax response? Or is  it being loaded with the initial file load. See this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

Comment: shigeya - the partial name is _statusform.html.erb. The link calling this jquery dialog script is index.html.erb.

kyle - tried putting quotes around statusform. same result.

checking out the railscast now

Comment: Ok in reviewing the railscast I think the answer to a previous question regarding the file names, the .js code is in a .js file not a .js.erb file.

So in summary, the link is located in index.html.erb, which calls a dialog function script in a file named work_orders.js which in turn is supposed to be serving _statusform.html.erb inside the dialog.

I'm still reviewing this railscast episode and trying to get my brain around this. The railscast is 4 years old and I started out on rails 3.1 which is part of my challenge with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if your code is not being processed as erb prior to be sent out to the client.

I'd recommend reviewing this Railscast:

["Railscast 136 - JQuery"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery)

It will walk you through exactly how to do what you're having an issue with.

Comment: Thanks I'm checking this out now.